# Background image move from left to right

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on app. in which login screen have a bcakground image. I want to move left to right this background image.how can i do this.?

A sample code i have using but this will move the image and left the layout balnk. i dont want it.

```
    ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(5);
    animation.setRepeatMode(2);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
```

I just want to implement as like this application screen :

check this [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist&hl=en) login screen in device. login screen have an image in background. and this image move from left to right. How can i achieve this process.please assist me.

[image]

Comment: Plz show some code where you added your custom background...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html).

set the scaleType of the ImageView to matrix.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />
```

then translate the matrix used by the ImageView a little bit to the right every milliseconds.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
img_animation.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```